# JCL - SORTIN added dynamically

Tags: mainframe, jcl, dfsort

Would like to know how to include in a SORT step a file that has the SORTIN content, meaning that the file has been created dynamically and its content is something like this

`//SORTIN   DD DSN=DES.LQHISE03.ENTRADA,DISP=SHR`

Comment: Can you add information about what you've tried?  Specifically, for a failing JOB can you provide the output so we can help you more effectively?

Comment: is there a specific reason you need to dynamically allocate a new file every time rather than using a GDG?

Comment: @SaggingRufus Good question, I took it to mean that he created the file in a previous step and wanted to provide it as input to a sort PROC

Comment: @Hogstrom even if he did, we could allocate the GDG using BPXWDYN and just use current generation in the next step.

Comment: Please clarify on the downvote. As per OP's ask, he has to include the SORTIN content to the SORT step and the SORTIN content is in a file. As per my understanding, OP is trying to tailor the JCL.

Comment: @SaggingRufus What is really needed is for the poster to clarify his goals, issues and what they have tried.  Otherwise we're guessing at options for a problem that is not clearly articulated

Comment: @SrinivasanJv I did clarify with a comment on your answer.

Comment: If you are creating the SORTIN DD statement 'dynamically' then why not the whole job(step)?

Answer (score -1):

**Step 1:** Please have the following 3 datasets.

Dataset 1: Job card and the EXEC statement.

```
//JOBNAME JOB ('ACCOUNT INFORMATION'),          
//    JOBCARD,CLASS=2,MSGCLASS=H,NOTIFY=&SYSUID 
//STEP1   EXEC PGM=SORT
```

Dataset 2:  SORTIN content  - This should be the dynamically created file.

```
//SORTIN   DD DSN=DES.LQHISE03.ENTRADA,DISP=SHR
```

Dataset 3: Rest of the content

```
//SORTOUT DD DSN=OUTPUT.DATASET.NAME,       
//        DISP=(,CATLG,DELETE),             
//        SPACE=(CYL,(100,0),RLSE),         
//        DCB=(LRECL=80,RECFM=FB,BLKSIZE=0) 
//SYSOUT  DD SYSOUT=*                       
//SYSIN   DD *                              
  SORT FIELDS=COPY
/*
//IDCAMS   EXEC PGM=IDCAMS,COND=(0,LT,STEP1)
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*
//DD1   DD DISP=SHR,DSN=YOUR.PDS
 DELETE 'YOUR.PDS(MEMBER)' FILE(DD1)
/*
```

**Step 2:** Concatenate the datasets.

```
//STEP2   EXEC PGM=IEBGENER
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                       
//SYSUT1   DD DSN=Dataset 1,DISP=SHR             
//         DD DSN=Dataset 2,DISP=SHR             
//         DD DSN=Dataset 3,DISP=SHR             
//SYSUT2   DD DSN=Sort Step,
//        DISP=(,CATLG,DELETE),             
//        SPACE=(CYL,(100,0),RLSE),         
//        DCB=(LRECL=80,RECFM=FB,BLKSIZE=0)            
//SYSIN    DD DUMMY
```

**Step 3:** Have IEBGENER to write the Sort Step (output from STEP 2) as a member in a PDS.

```
//STEP3   EXEC PGM=IEBGENER,COND=(0,LT,STEP2)
//SYSUT1   DD DSN=*.STEP2.SYSUT2,DISP=SHR                         
//SYSUT2   DD DSN=YOUR.PDS(MEMBER),DISP=SHR           
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                                        
//SYSIN    DD DUMMY
```

You will now have the complete JCL in a member inside your PDS (Note: The member inside the PDS will be deleted after the completion of the SORT job). You just need to submit the member. You can make use of the IKJEFT01 utility to run a TSO function, LISTDS. This function displays data set attributes. If a member exists, RC 0 is issued & you may add code to SUBMIT the member, else you may issue some return code (to signify non availability of the member). More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51420681/4626398)

Comment: This is not what OP is asking. OP has a file that was dynamically allocated and wants to use that as SYSIN for a sort step

Comment: This answer is very broad based on the narrow question.  All of the additional steps are confusing as they are not needed for the question at hand.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your comments. It's not possible to do it as Srinivasan Jv suggested as I do not know on advance the name of the file(s) that will be in the sortin, I just know the name of the file that will contain the sortin statement. This is part of an archiving process in previous jcls the files are being created based on the year, so in advance we don´t know how many we will have.

Comment: Hi @NatBI as per my answer, it's not needed that you should know the name of the file(s) that will be in SORTIN. If you know the name of the file that will contain the SORTIN statement, you can merely consider that as Dataset 2 shown in Step 1.

Comment: If I'm clear, you have the SORTIN statement in a dataset and your ultimate objective is to run the SORT step using the files given in the SORTIN statement. Kindly clarify.

Comment: Yes Srinivasan Jv that's whay I need. My doubt, if I include my file as dataset 2 in Step 1 I will just have a sort fields=copy for my dataset, I don't follow what that step is doing and how it can help. Thanks

Comment: Hi @NatBI In Step 1, I have shown 3 datasets. These 3 datasets combined together will make a job step in Step 2. The job step is now available in a dataset (Sort Step). You will have the contents of the Sort Step dataset in a PDS after step 3. You can then look for a method to submit the job step from the PDS. Just for the sake of understanding, I've shown SORT FIELDS=COPY. If you want to add more SORT statements, you can do that in Dataset 3. Hope this helps. Please let me know if you need more details.